# How to mention a variable inside a jinja block

Tags: jinja2, flask-wtforms

I have a form in my html, I use flask_wtf to help with forms and make it easier, I'm trying to set a default value inside my input, but I cannot mention a variable inside a jinja block.
this code should help you understand what I mean:

```
{{form.username(class="hidden", type="text", value="{{application.username}}")}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{reject.username(class="hidden", type="text", value=application.username)}}
```

I removed the double parenthesis on application.username and also removed the quotations.
that fixed it.